# How to subscribe for Developer Org?

Tags: developer, developer-edition

It's a very simple question but I don't know where am I supposed to subscribe a Dev Org, a link would be helpful.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/signup?d=70130000000td6N

Comment: Like the answers said developer.salesforce.com is the site you need.  It also holds all of the documentation, articles, blogs, etc.  It is a great starting resource.

Comment: Good point about docs and such.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go to https://developer.salesforce.com/ to sign up.

In the upper right hand side of the screen there is the link to Sign Up.

[image]

You will be routed to the Developer Sign Up Page and sign up. You will get confirmation email and use that to login.

[image]